# How to export mongoose.model(xxx, xxx) as TypeScript class

Tags: typescript, export, mongoose-schema

Hot to export mongoose.model(xxx, xxx) as TypeScript class?
Cloud you help me?
Thanks a lot !!!!

```js
store_entity.ts
export const StoreSchema: Schema = new Schema({
    name: {
        type: String
    }
}, {
        autoCreate: true,
        versionKey: false
    }
);

StoreSchema.index({ name: 1 }, { unique: true });

export const StoreEntity = mongoose.model('store', StoreSchema, 'store');
```

```js
test.ts
import { StoreEntity } from './store_entity';

function display(storeEntity: StoreEntity) {
    console.log(storeEntity);
}
```

But I have the error tip:

```
'StoreEntity' refers to a value, but is being used as a type here.ts(2749)
```

in test.ts